# What is this js syntax called?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if there is a specific name for this way to pull object properties into their own variable? If there is a name, does anyone know?

```
var object = {
  something: 'a string',
  another: 'another string',
}
var { something, another } = object;
```

Comment: [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Wanted to know so I can check if I can use it an older version of node.

Comment: The newer versions of node do support this @Dan

Comment: @James111 Yeah, I saw that [v6+](http://node.green/#destructuring--declarations) supports it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object destructuring, read up on it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

A lot of this new syntax isn't fully implemented in all js engines, so be careful when using it!

If you want to learn more about it, checkout this tutorial:

https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/learning-es6-destructuring/

Answer (score 1):

This is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).